# Let $a$ be a real number satisfying $0<a<1$. Evaluate $\lim\left (\frac{a^n+a^{3n}}{1+a^2}\right)^{1/n}$

Tags: calculus, limits, logarithms

let a be a real number satisfying $0<a<1$. Evaluate $$\lim \left(\frac{a^n+a^{3n}}{1+a^2}\right)^{1/n}$$

I feel i should be doing this my squeeze so i wrote this:
$$\left(\frac{a^{3n}}{1+a^2}\right)^{1/n} \le \left(\frac{a^n+a^{3n}}{1+a^2}\right)^{1/n} \le \left(\frac{2}{1+a^2}\right)^{1/n}$$

But I'm stuck here.
I'm not sure if further extending the inequality will work i.e.

Thanks to Daniel Fischer,
$$\left(\frac{a^{n}}{2}\right)^{1/n} \le \left(\frac{a^{n}}{1+a^2}\right)^{1/n} \le \left(\frac{a^n+a^{3n}}{1+a^2}\right)^{1/n} \le \left(\frac{2a^n}{1+a^2}\right)^{1/n} \le \left(\frac{2a^n}{1}\right)^{1/n}$$

in hindsight, after doing the limits right, i got a limit of a. is that right?

What if $a>1$? how should I proceed then?

Comment: Try looking at the logarithm...

Comment: Use $a^n < a^n + a^{3n} < 2a^n$.

Comment: When $a>1$, use $a^{3n}<a^n+a^{3n}<2a^{3n}.$

Answer (score 1):

$$\left(\frac{a^n+a^{3n}}{1+a^2}\right)^{1/n}=a\left(\frac{1+a^{2n}}{1+a^2}\right)^{1/n}\;\;(**)$$

and now we can use the squeeze theorem

$$\frac1{2}\le\left(\frac{1+a^{2n}}{1+a^2}\right)\le\frac21=2\implies$$

$$1\xleftarrow[\infty\leftarrow n]{}\frac1{\sqrt[n]{2}}\le\left(\frac{1+a^{2n}}{1+a^2}\right)^{1/n}\le\sqrt[n]2\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}1$$

so by (**) the limit is $\;a\;$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{align}
\ln((\frac{a^n+a^{3n}}{1+a^2})^{\frac1n})&=\frac1n\ln(\frac{a^n+a^{3n}}{1+a^2})\\
&=\frac1n(\ln(a^n+a^{3n})-\ln(1+a^2))\\
&=\ln(a)+\frac1n\ln(1+a^{2n})-\frac1n\ln(1+a^{2})
\end{align}
$$
And So, when $n\to \infty$, $$\lim \ln((\frac{a^n+a^{3n}}{1+a^2})^{\frac1n})=\ln(a)$$ Thus, $$\lim_{n\to \infty}(\frac{a^n+a^{3n}}{1+a^2})^{\frac1n}=a$$